# Retina images, non retina devices

Tags: ios

I have an app that runs on iPhone and iPad, most of the intended devices for this app will be retina devices except for the iPad mini. I have a lot of images to include in this app.
My question is, if I decide to go with the @2x images only, will iOS downgrade them to non retina devices? so I ship only retina images? If that is correct is it a bad idea to implement?

Comment: I have a little Mac tool I got from somewhere called "rescale@2x".  It takes your @2x images and creates "normal" copies for them, so you can have both.

Answer (score 0):

iOS will not downgrade those images. But if you are setting the frames of your imageviews carefully, it will not create any problem.

Comment: really? it won't do the downgrade? it usually does an upgrade from non retina to retina images? can I force a downgrade?

Comment: No, it will not downgrade or upgrade. But if your frame is small and image is big, it will accomodate the bigger image in smaller frame and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

If your image view have contentMode = scale your images will be scaled to display correctly on non-retina

But there is some problems:

1) if you display scaled retina image on non-retina device you will have blurred edges on image. So if you want to use this images for UI - it will be bad idea.

2) Sometime xCode storyboards does not scale correctly image if you have only @2x image (for example in uibuttons)

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning the images in Interface Builder, and you set the image property on a `UIImageView` to `image@2x.png`, for example, iOS will not know that it's a high resolution "2x" image. In fact, on a retina display, iOS will look for an image named `image@2x@2x.png`. Since it won't find it, it will set the scale factor of the image to 1.0.

The `contentMode` property (just "mode" in XCode) will decide if any scaling of the image occurs to fit the constraints of the UIImageView. You may wish to set the mode to "Aspect Fit" to get the high resolution image to scale as needed for both retina and non-retina displays. In general, the image will display as seen in Interface Builder.

If you are using UIImage's `imageNamed` or similar function to load the image, and just specify `image` (where "image.png" doesn't exist, but "image@2x.png" does), then iOS will actually find the image on a non-retina display, though the scale factor will be 1.0. As previously, you'll need to scale it to fit your view. The image will work normally on a retina device, and the scale factor will be set to 2.0, since iOS looks for a "2x" image first, and it doesn't matter if the other file exists or not.

This is from Apple's documentation on [`imageNamed`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a):

> On a device running iOS 4 or later, the behavior is identical if the
>   device’s screen has a scale of 1.0. If the screen has a scale of 2.0,
>   this method first searches for an image file with the same filename
>   with an @2x suffix appended to it. For example, if the file’s name is
>   button, it first searches for button@2x. If it finds a 2x, it loads
>   that image and sets the scale property of the returned UIImage object
>   to 2.0. Otherwise, it loads the unmodified filename and sets the scale
>   property to 1.0. See iOS App Programming Guide for more information on
>   supporting images with different scale factors.

If at all possible, you really should include both retina and non-retina images. Using higher-resolution images than necessary negatively affects memory and performance.